# Pdfview Library not loading using url

Tags: java, android, android-studio, pdf

I want to download pdf file from firebase storage and show it in Pdfview but it is not loading with the url that is provided by fireabse. It does not shows any error just the page remain blank. I

```
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (firebaseUser != null) {
            currentUserId = firebaseUser.getUid();

            pdfView = findViewById( R.id.pdfViewRead );

            pdfUrl = getIntent().getStringExtra( "pdfUrl" );
            String bookKey = getIntent().getStringExtra( "bookKey" );

            Log.i( "URL", pdfUrl );
            Log.i( "URL2", Uri.parse( pdfUrl ).toString() );

            pdfUri = Uri.parse( pdfUrl );

            displayPdf();


        }
    }

    private void displayPdf() {
        pdfView.fromUri(  pdfUri )
                .enableSwipe( true )
                .enableAnnotationRendering( true )
                .scrollHandle( new DefaultScrollHandle( this ) )
                .load();

    }
```

Comment: Is url contain http or https?

Comment: @AbhayKoradiya  it is of type https , it is firebase storage  download link.. Eg = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/online-reader-38509.appspot.com/o/Bank%20Statement.pdf?alt=media&token=b2a94f8-bdce-44db-ac8c-e119ee28c76f"

Comment: no it's not pdf link.

Comment: @AbhayKoradiya Why?? i have uploaded pdf file. where things goes wrong??

Comment: I think It only support link with ".pdf" at the end.

Answer (score 0):

for those who find this error in future here is the solution.
**You can not load pdf directly from url. First you need to download it in local storage of your device and then load it using fromFile i have like this look.**
Step 1) you have download file from firebase storage to your local device as permanent or temporarty i have downloaded temporay file.
Step 2) load pdf to your app using downloaded file
Step 3) kudos you are done
**Happy coding***

```
``firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
    if (firebaseUser != null) {
        currentUserId = firebaseUser.getUid();

        pdfView = findViewById( R.id.pdfViewRead );
        progressBar = findViewById( R.id.progressBarActivityRead );

        //pdfUrl = getIntent().getStringExtra( "pdfUrl" );
        bookKey = getIntent().getStringExtra( "bookKey" );
        pdfName = getIntent().getStringExtra( "pdfName" );
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference( "RecentRead" ).child( currentUserId )
        .child( bookKey );

        //     Log.i( "URL", pdfUrl );
```

//            Log.i( "URL2", Uri.parse( pdfUrl ).toString() );

//            pdfUri = Uri.parse( pdfUrl );

```
        //  Toast.makeText( this, pdfUrl + "   " + bookKey, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        //   displayPdf();
        try {
            readData();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private void readData() throws IOException {
    progressBar.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
    final File outputFile = File.createTempFile( "file", "pdf" );

    StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().
            child( "Users" ).child( currentUserId ).child( "Pdf" )
            .child( pdfName );

    storageReference.getFile( outputFile ).addOnSuccessListener( new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

            Toast.makeText( ReadPdfActivity.this, "File Downloaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
           displayPdf( outputFile )
        }
    } ).addOnProgressListener( new OnProgressListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onProgress(@NonNull FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            // Add Progress
        }`enter code here`
    } );
}

private void displayPdf(File file) {
    progressBar.setVisibility( View.INVISIBLE );
    pdfView.fromFile( file )
            .defaultPage( 20 )
            .enableSwipe( true )
            .swipeHorizontal( true )
            .pageSnap( true )
            .autoSpacing( true )
            .pageFling( true )
            .enableAnnotationRendering( true )
            .scrollHandle( new DefaultScrollHandle( this ) )
            .load();
}``
```